# Im trying to select a div element by class AND title

Tags: javascript, html, css

I seen how to select a `div` element by `title` or by `class` only, but I am trying to select an element using both.

I tried putting it in a format like below and it did not work. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
document.querySelector(‘div.myClass [title=“CoolTitleYeah”]’);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply delete the space, with the space you are selecting any children inside the `div.myClass` with `title` equals to `CoolTitleYeah`

```
document.querySelector('div.myClass[title="CoolTitleYeah"]')
```

Comment: what if the class name is like "ClasslistItem__Title-sc-150ez25-7 hgdGGJ". I get invalid or unexpected token error in the console.

Comment: Hi, this means the div has 2 classes, it is converted in JS as: `document.querySelector('div.ClasslistItem__Title-sc-150ez25-7.hgdGGJ[title="CoolTitleYeah"]')`

Comment: Ankabot is right – you can also use the attribute selector on both the class names and the title – like:
`document.querySelector('div[class="ClasslistItem__Title-sc-150ez25-7 hgdGGJ"][title="CoolTitleYeah"]')`

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.myClass,div[title="CoolTitleYeah"]');
```

Comment: This is close but it returns an array in the console, and I only want to select the second result by itself.

Comment: can you not target second item from that array like [1] ?